# Reputation Leagues: monthly reputation bigger than total reputation

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

I looked to the Reputation League   and noticed that I had more monthly reputation, namely 2929, than total reputation, namely 2848, though I registered on May 1, so I haven't got any reputation before this month.

Not that I really care about those few points, but I'm curious why. Is it a bug or just a matter of different counting?

[image]

Comment: You apparently awarded a bounty, which accounts for 50 of the points I guess. You've also received a few downvotes. I don't know for the rest.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I have offered 250 rep in bounties and awarded 200 rep in bounties.

Comment: On meta.SE I found this: [Year reputation greater than total reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146212/year-reputation-greater-than-total-reputation). It links further to this: [Why is my total reputation less than my monthly reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141628/why-is-my-total-reputation-less-than-my-monthly-reputation). Maybe there you can find out details about what counts where.

Comment: Maybe you could add screenshot to your post, since the numbers shown there are very likely to change. I will add at least a link: http://stackexchange.com/leagues/21/month/math/2015-05-01/236048?sort=reputationchange#236048

Comment: @MartinSleziak Done. The links were also helpful.