# Discrepancy in reputation change between reputation league and user list

Tags: support, reputation, users, reputation-leagues

When I click on the [users tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/), it gives me a list of people who gained the most reputation in the last week:

[image: Users tab]

However, when I look at the [weekly leaderboards](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/69/week/math), it seems to say something completely different:

[image: Leaderboard]

Here, José Carlos Santos is ranked first, for example. What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: I think it's to do with when the different views are updated; the leaderboards update every 24 hours as I recall, but I don't think I know when the Users page updates.  They're not real-time though.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is relevant here, but I will remind that some reputation changes are excluded from the reputation leagues See this post and also the posts which are linked there: [Total reputation > total reputation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32624). (For example, if some user downvoted several answers, the -1 for the downvotes will not be reflected in the reputation league.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be one or two things:

1. [caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) - reputation leagues are updated [once a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/347659/295232), the `/users` page more often.
2. The 'reputation change' column in the reputation league includes reputation from so-called private reputation events: see [Why is my total reputation less than my monthly reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141628/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. For example, reputation gained on answers to question which were afterwards deleted are counted in this column.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Just to clarify: do the weekly reputation leaderboards measure how much reputation you have gained in the past $7$ days; or do they measure how much you have gained in that particular week (starting on Monday or Sunday)?

Comment: They tell you how much you gained in that particular week.